# yguard remove default type constructor

Tags: java, obfuscation, yguard

I have some problem with the yguard library when i make an obfuscated jar.

Yguard remove default contructor type like this (no parameters, no visibility) :

```
   Test(){

   }
```

Do you know why it remove this type of constructor ?

And do you have a solution to this problem ?

Thank you,

Best regards,

Comment: Nobody already have this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe yGuard removes such constructors because of [shrink task](http://www.yworks.com/products/yguard/yguard_ant_howto.html#shrink). Just exclude your class from shrinking like this (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031141/java-obfuscation-using-yguard-with-a-service-provider-interface-in-the-mix) by predi):

```
<shrink logfile="obfuscate_shrink_log.xml">
<property name="error-checking" value="pedantic"/>
<keep>
    <method name="void main(java.lang.String[])" class="package.path.to.main.Class"/>
    <class name="package.path.to.my.implementation.of.DatatypeLibraryFactory" methods="public"/>
    <class classes="public"/>
</keep>
```

Or use techniques described in troubleshooting section of yGuard documentation (http://www.yworks.com/products/yguard/yguard_ant_howto.html#hints).

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I just ran into this myself.